# How to Mysql JDBC Driver to android studio

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, driver

I want to connect to remote sql database via jdbc 
I work on Android Studio 
But when executing I got this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

So How can I add The JDBC Driver to Android Studio ??

Comment: Please reconsider this. JDBC is not designed for use this way. In particular, you will wind up having to have database account data, including passwords, in your app, which is bad from a security standpoint.

Comment: I don't know why people talk about this stupid security issue all the time. The OP could be writing a MySQL client, but everyone just presumes the OP doesn't notice such obvious security problem.

Answer (score 15):

1. [Download JDBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and extract the *.jar* file
2. Open Android Studio and your project of interest
3. Open your Left Panel, in the *1.Project* Tab
4. Right Click on your application module folder and go to ***New* > *Module*** and there Select ***Import .JAR/.AAR Package***.
5. In the first field you must insert the directory of the previously extracted ***.jar*** file. You can browse your folders by clicking on the far right icon with the 3 dots ***(...)***

Once you have selected the ***.jar*** file and your project *Synchronizes* you can move on to the next steps:

1. Right Click again on your application module folder and select *Open Module Settings*
2. In the left navigation pane of the newly opened window, go to the category *Modules* and select ***app*** and then the ***Dependencies*** tab.
3. There click on the green plus (***+***), and select ***Module Dependencies***. Select the *mysql* module.
4. Click ***OK***, and close all the opened windows. A ***Synchronization*** process should take place once more.
5. If everything has been done correctly, under your *app module folder* you should see a *mysql-connector-java* module folder.
6. Don't forget to include the classes you want in your code.

**Troubleshooting** 
In my case I had to uninstall the module and re-install it. The reason was that the module was compiled with Java 1.8 instead of 1.7 (currently supported by Android Studio ver:1.5.1).

Comment: i complete all settings..i check everything. but my connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the official site of MySQL to download the [JDBC][2].

Then you only need to add the library to Android Studio like any other library.

Comment: I Know that But my question  was how to add the  driver to android studio ...not like  a usual library

Comment: The driver JDBC are an usual library ;)